# Nested include tag is not working in android xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following RelativeLayout, call it layout_dog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            ... />

        <TextView
           ... />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        layout="@layout/center_overlay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I view layout_dog in the `Graphical Layout` everything looks fine.

But then I have another layout file, a LinearLayout called layout_book. When I `include` layout_dog inside layout_book, center_overlay does not show in layout_book.
Does anyone know how to get this right?

Answer (score 0):

There actually no problem with android. I was including the wrong xml file in layout_book